# closeModal [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, modal

We have a lightning aura component that overrides the edit of a custom object and we basically have a container that calls a lightning aura component.

We have a modal that closes the component and destroys it but we started getting the following error:

[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')]

Below is a code snippet and screenshots.

```
    closeModal : function(component,event,helper){

        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); 

        var myRecordId = component.get('v.recordId');
        var navigateLightning = component.find('navService');
        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: myRecordId,
                objectApiName: 'My_CustomObject__c',
                actionName: 'view'                
            }
        };
        component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
        navigateLightning.navigate(pageReference,false);   

        this.destroy();


},
```

[image]

[image]